# What is the easiest way to get Current Route Path Name in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I was looking for a good way to get the current route's path name. This was the easiest I could find.

```
this.route.snapshot.firstChild.url[0].path
```

Is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. Here is what I found that I had to do.

```
router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
  console.log(event);
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
    this.currentUrl = event.url;
  }
});
```

Comment: Or shorter:
`router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url);`

Comment: It works like charm. Do not forget to import { Event, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationError } from '@angular/router';

Answer (score 33):

easiest way to find current path is either you directly use

```
this.router.url
```

or you can check current path on every router change using its events like this

```
this.router.events.subscribe((res) => { 
    console.log(this.router.url,"Current URL");
})
```

where `router` here is instance created in constructor like this

```
constructor(private router: Router){ ... }
```

Comment: Without imports or even getting the router through the constructor? Doesn't work.

Comment: i have already share code to provide router through constructor. and obviously imports are required. anyways why downvote @FeloVilches

Answer (score 4):

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(route);
}
```

or

```
constructor(private router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(...);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.