# RouterStateSnapshot upcoming absolute url in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to get the absolute url for upcoming route(To state) from RouterStateSnapshot in angular 2. Currently I am only getting the relative url like /product not http://localhost:4200/product. I can't use this.router.navigateByUrl('/product'); because I need to send the absolute path to non-angular code.If I have to map it to angularjs ui-router, we had something like this.

```
var absoluteUrl = $state.href(toState, toParams, { absolute: true })
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to get Current Route Path Name in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360625/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-current-route-path-name-in-angular-4)

Comment: @Vikas - It's not the same. Please check my updated question.